# How can I make a bash script alias that accepts inputs?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, bash-alias

I currently have a bash script that starts up a python file like so

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting main.py in Production folder"
cd Production
python main.py
```

`main.py` is actually supposed to take in 2 parameters, so normally I would run it like

`main.py integerInput integerInput` , so `main.py 5 5`

I also have a bash alias like so
 `alias runner='. ~/runner.sh`

How can I adjust the bash or the alias so that I can start up my python file with the `runner` keyword along with some inputs,

so `runner 5 5`

Comment: You shouldn't run scripts with the `.` command unless there's some special reason to. Make the script executable (`chmod +x ~/runner.sh`) and since it has a proper shebang you can just run it as `~/runner.sh`. Even better, you can remove the `.sh` extension (it isn't doing anything useful), put the file in a directory in your `$PATH`, and you can run it directly without the alias.

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my own question:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting main.py in Production folder with arguments $1 and $2"
cd Production
python main.py $1 $2
```

Comment: Huge step in the right direction, but [quote right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618): `python main.py "$1" "$2"`